# Convert XML Data to Flat File in R

Tags: xml, r, soap, statistics, regression

I am working with some XML data that I need to convert to a flat file so I can do statistical analysis.  I am analyzing the data using R.  Here is what a sample of the data looks like:

```
<production xmlns="" diffgr:id="production1130" msdata:rowOrder="1129">
  <ENTITY_ID>116484210</ENTITY_ID>
  <LIQ>0</LIQ>
  <GAS>163</GAS>
  <WTR>0</WTR>
  <WCNT>1</WCNT>
  <DAYS>0</DAYS>
</production>
<production xmlns="" diffgr:id="production1131" msdata:rowOrder="1130">
  <ENTITY_ID>116484210</ENTITY_ID>
  <LIQ>12</LIQ>
  <GAS>130</GAS>
  <WTR>0</WTR>
  <WCNT>1</WCNT>
  <DAYS>0</DAYS>
</production>
```

I would like this to translate to a flat file that looks like this:

PRODUCTION_ID, ENTITY_ID, LIQ, GAS, WTR, WCNT, DAYS

Any suggestions?

Thanks, Z

Comment: Well, the `XML` package would be the obvious place to start.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simple example:

```
install.packages("XML")
library("XML")
doc = xmlInternalTreeParse("/Users/ras/test.xml") # your path goes here
myframe = xmlToDataFrame(doc)
myframe
```

Yields:

```
  ENTITY_ID LIQ GAS WTR WCNT DAYS
1 116484210   0 163   0    1    0
2 116484210  12 130   0    1    0
```

test.xml being:

```
<stuff>
    <production xmlns="" diffgr:id="production1130" msdata:rowOrder="1129">
      <ENTITY_ID>116484210</ENTITY_ID>
      <LIQ>0</LIQ>
      <GAS>163</GAS>
      <WTR>0</WTR>
      <WCNT>1</WCNT>
      <DAYS>0</DAYS>
    </production>
    <production xmlns="" diffgr:id="production1131" msdata:rowOrder="1130">
      <ENTITY_ID>116484210</ENTITY_ID>
      <LIQ>12</LIQ>
      <GAS>130</GAS>
      <WTR>0</WTR>
      <WCNT>1</WCNT>
      <DAYS>0</DAYS>
    </production>
</stuff>
```

Comment: Cool, I would be thrilled if you pressed the checkmark next to the post, meaning you accept the solution to the problem :-)